# Get properties file from CDI bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

How can I get a properties file from CDI bean, I mean properties file for internationalization purposes as mentioned [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/).

In `@ManagedBean` everything is simple `@ManagedProperty(name="....")` but I can't encounter the way to achieve the same in CDI bean.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, CDI doesn't support the kind of field-level access that `@ManagedProperty` gives (where you can have `@ManagedProperty(name="#{msgs.title}")`). If you want that level of control in CDI, you'll have to write a CDI [Producer](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html).

Considering that the resource bundle is simply a class of `ResourceBundle`, you could easily obtain your defined bundle with:

```
    FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ctxt.getApplication().getResourceBundle(ctxt, aValue);
    bundle.get("title");
```

Alternatively, you could simply inject either your `FacesContext` or `Application` into your bean:

```
    @Inject
    Application theApplication


    public void getBundle{
        ResourceBundle bundle = theApplication.getResourceBundle(ctxt, aValue);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for internationalization support within CDI for JSF purposes, you may want to look at DeltaSpike's [JSF](http://deltaspike.apache.org/jsf.html) module.  It builds off of the core i18n support available in [core](http://deltaspike.apache.org/core.html#messages-i18n).